# A reduce function (written in Python) calls "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" but it's acting on a list of lists

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

```
while reduce(lambda x, y: x[0] + y[0], final_assignments, 0) < min:
```

final_assignments is `[[5,100]]` when the function raises "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". I don't understand what's the problem and would like some help.

Comment: Do you want to do sum of array? It's easier with `sum()` than `reduce()`

Comment: Didn't even know about that function, thanks! anyway I found the fix for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, the initial value 0 isn't a list so I can't add 0[0] + y[0].
Instead, the lambda should choose what value to pick based on the type:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x[0]+y[0] if type(x) == list else x+y[0], final_assignments, 0)
```

Comment: The `if` is redundant, only the `else` branch will ever be taken — see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reduction acts on two items: the previously returned result, and the next input.

Since your result type is `int`, so does the first argument type need to be `int`:

```
while reduce(lambda x, y: x + y[0], final_assignments, 0) < min:
```